# Hangman game - C

Tags: c, performance

Im doing a hangman game as a school project but Im facing an issue:

```
do{
    system("cls");
    // Header of the game
    printf("\n HANGMAN GAME\n\n\n");

    // Present letters found
    for (i=0; word[i]!='\0'; i++)
        printf (" %c  ", word_2[i]);
        printf("\n");

    // Present positions to the letters
    for (i=0; word[i]!='\0'; i++)
        printf("___ ");
        printf("\n");

    // ****PLAYER'S ANSWERS*****

    // Read player's answers
    printf("\n\n Whats your guess + <enter>: ");
    scanf("%c", &letter);
    scanf("%c", &c);

    // Verify if the letter is in the word
    found=0;
    for(i=0; word[i]!='\0'; i++)
    if (word[i] == letter){
        word_2[i] = letter;
        corrects++;
        max_attemps--;
        found = 1;
        printf("\nWell done, %s. You have now %d attempts\n\n", name, max_attemps);
        system("pause");

    }
    if(found == 0){
        max_attemps--;
        printf("\nOh no, %s. You have now %d attempts\n\n", name, max_attemps);
        system("pause");
    }

    if (max_attemps <= 0 || corrects == lenght) {
        end = 1;
    }
} while (end == 0);
```

When I got a right letter that have two or more position in the word it takes from me two or more attempts because of the `system("pause")` when in fact just had to takes me one. But if I don't put the `system("pause")` the board will be cleared before I can see the message. Anyone knows what can I do to solve this? I'll be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `found` flag only after you have scanned the whole word:

```
    // Verify if the letter is in the word
found=0;
for(i=0; word[i]!='\0'; i++)
if (word[i] == letter){
    word_2[i] = letter;
    corrects++;
    max_attemps--;
    found = 1;

// comment out
//        printf("\nWell done, %s. You have now %d attempts\n\n", name, max_attemps);
//        system("pause");

}
    if(found == 1)
{
            printf("\nWell done, %s. You have now %d attempts\n\n", name, max_attemps);
            system("pause");
}



else{
    max_attemps--;
    printf("\nOh no, %s. You have now %d attempts\n\n", name, max_attemps);
    system("pause");
}

if (max_attemps <= 0 || corrects == lenght) {
    end = 1;
}
```